# Is [numbering] tag useful or too vague?

Tags: discussion, status-planned, tag-cleanup-request

I am looking at the tag on SU, called [numbering](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/numbering). It appears to be very broad and not useful at collecting similar questions. Should it be there, or removed?

Comment: I can't think of a use for that tag, outside of a document-centric site, and maybe not even then.

Comment: It's only use is when combined with another more useful tag, such as microsoft-word, to properly define what you are numbering. As such it is a meta-tag and should be removed​.

Comment: You could say.... it's numbers up!

Answer (score 14):

I see no way that this tag is even remotely useful. I'm amazed that it's amassed over 100 questions.

We should burninate it.